# Rendering images in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I can't seem to get images to display in my react app created using create-react-app.
This is my directory structure:

```
build
node_modules
public
src
  assets
  components
    header
      ImportingComponent.js
  data
    data.js
  css
```

The path to the image lives in an object in the data directory in the `data.js` file

```
import asdfgProfile from "../assets/IMG_20181128_182110.jpg";
import zxcvbProfile from "../assets/38492604_10157553680894256_362213635956670464_n.jpg";

const f =[
    {
        "name": "asdfg",
        "thumbnail": {asdfgProfile}
    },
    {
        "name": "zxcvb",
        "thumbnail": {zxcvbProfile}
    }

];
export default founders;
```

This is code in the component that calls it,

```
{props.founders.map( item =>
        <div className="firstFounder">
             <img src={(item.thumbnail)}></img>
             <h2>{item.name}</h2>
             <h3> {item.designation}</h3>
             <p>{item.blurb}</p>
        </div>
 )}
```

The image doesn't seem to render. What am I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const f =[
    {
        "name": "asdfg",
        "thumbnail": {asdfgProfile}
    },
    {
        "name": "zxcvb",
        "thumbnail": {zxcvbProfile}
    }

];
```

Remove brackets from `{zxcvbProfile}`, `{asdfgProfile}`, you're creating a `thumbnail: { }` object, not providing a value.